# formatCurrency in js.js returns 0,00

Tags: error, javascript, currency

The function formatCurrency in js.js is returning 0.0, i have followed the flow and it goes well until here

```
if (format.pattern.indexOf('{sign}') == -1) {
    pattern = s + format.pattern;
} else {
    pattern = format.pattern.replace('{sign}', s);
}

return pattern.replace('%s',r).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
```

if i return price before this it returns the actual price but dont show the sign. i havend changed anything in the code. any idea where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to implement formatCurrency?  Personally, i'd use something like this to do the job:

```
Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($product->getFinalPrice(), true);
```